# Absolute link in jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug, keystonejs

I am running keystonejs (Nodejs + expressjs + jade ), and trying to add absolute links to my pages. Every link I add is a relative link though, and always routes to my site. 
Below, post.url has the value "www.google.com":

a(href=post.url, target=' ')

The result is -> localhost:8080//www.google.com

The only solution I have currently found is to add "http://" in front:
a(href="http://"+post.url, target=' ')

which works, creating the link http://www.google.com.
This is a bad solution though because pages with https do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never tryed **keystonejs**, but i use to do the next and maybe it can work in your case.

Try with this:

```
a(href="//"+post.url, target=' ')
```

If you left the `//` alone, the browser will request the url with the protocol used in the main page.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly!
I can websites now and it directs to http or https correctly!

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap that with encodeURIComponent.

So your link will look like `a(href=encodeURIComponent(post.url), target=' ')`.

It will escape necessary symbols and will show properly.